# Is setting object property:!object.propety volatile?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Does this code  mutate the object or is volatile in any other way?
How can I avoid it if it does?

```
const object = {property: false};
const test = {property: !object.property};
```

Comment: No, your code doesn't mutate any objects.

Comment: Try it in your console and you'll see what changes and what not. Experiment with different values and operators and you'll quickly understand how it works. If it's still unclear you could check some basic JavaScript tutorials or read the ECMAScript specs.

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded, so volatility isn't really an issue unless you reference free variables after an asynchronous operation. `var x = {foo:'bar'}; async function main ( ) { console.log( x ); await new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( resolve, 100 ) ); console.log( x ); } main( ); setTimeout( _ => x.foo = 'test', 0 );` is the only case you have to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't mutate anything. When you create `test`, the original `object` is not affected as `.property` is a boolean (and hence value type), so your new assignment is by value only.

```
const test = {property: !object.property}; // assigns a new value to a new reference
```

This, on the other hand does:

```
const object = {property: false};
object.property = !object.property; // mutating the object
const test = object; // copying the reference
```

You could do this, though:

```
const object = {property: false};
const test = {...object, property: !object.property}; // creates a copy of object and over-writes the value of the new property
```